# arcpy TypeError: narray.fields require

Tags: numpy, typeerror, arcpy

I am receiving a really unhelpful error message  'TypeError: narray.fields require' on doing the following;

I have a pandas data frame which I have converted to a numpy array using
    df.as_matrix()

this is the numpy array "npArrayIN" shape: (3, 10)

I then need to create a feature class - here is the call to the arcpy function which has the list of 10 fields I want to create but which crashes returning the error. All numbers are floating point.

```
arcpy.da.NumPyArrayToFeatureClass(npArrayIN, outputShape,    ("TID","X","Y","Z","H","D","WGS84Lat","WGS84Long","OFFSETA", "OFFSETB"), spRef)
```

Any suggestions gratefully received.

Thanks

Comment: Probably need to post your code and the stack trace in order to get better help.

Comment: I think you would make more progress with this by deleting your question here and asking it on the [gis.se] Stack Exchange instead.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried it with the "X","Y","Z" as the 1st three columns instead of leading it with "TID"?
Also, you may want to try it with only the xyz columns.

Comment: I think this would be better as a comment than an answer.